# Reliable docking charging connector?

Tags: connector, reliability, robot

I am designing a mobile robot which needs to re-charge in a docking station, but I'm having difficulty deciding what to do about the connector. I have two choices: design and make our own connector, or use an off-the-shelf connector.

The connector needs to carry 30V at 3A, and must survive at least a few hundred thousand mating cycles. Also, since it's going to be mated by a clumsy robot, it needs to be physically robust and easily mate even under non-ideal circumstances. The robot weighs only about 2kg, and so cannot produce enough force to mate a mains connector.

Ideally, I would like to design my own connector, so that I can design it to mate easily. But since connectors are a major source of unreliability, I feel this might be a bad idea.

Added: Existing docking connectors for most products tend to be small, fiddly, rated for less than 3A, and less than 10k mating cycles. Even standard 2.5mm pin DC jacks are only rated for 5k cycles. Larger connectors like mains plugs have quite a high insertion force, and don't seem to state their mating cycle rating.

Questions:

If I design my own connector, what should I do to ensure several hundred thousand mating cycles?

Are there any off-the-shelf connectors which might do the job?

Comment: What have you found so far? Docking connectors are not a new thing, what have you found other similar devices / products / projects using? It's rarely "ideal" to design your own parts like connectors when other people have done all the hard work (and a lot more of it) for you before.

Comment: @JohnU - Added. I really don't want to design my own connector. I'd rather use a COTS one, but if nothing is suitable (and looking at other docking robots which all seem to use custom ones too) then I'd like to ensure it's a reliable connector.

Comment: A horizontally-mounted horseshoe-shaped connector with torsion springs on the inside sides that carry the current.

Comment: With a decent mechanical alignment method on the dock, sprung connectors like this (or just pogo pins) could work: http://uk.farnell.com/okw-enclosures/a9178007/docking-station-contact-kit/dp/1236643

Comment: Are you charging it at 30V/3A? Automatic vacuum cleaners (iRobot etc) have bent bronze contacts on the charger side and spring leaf contacts on the robot's side.